# el template no se como realizarlo

Tags: c++, template

Quiero hacer un template

```
template<int... num; typename T>
T suma_mult(T x){}
```

¿Dónde sumo la multiplicación de un número por `T`? asi:

```
suma_mult<1,2,3>(3)/// return 1x3 +2x2+3x3
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), recuerda que puedes editar tu publicación para añadir detalles, código de lo que has intentado, para más dudas revisa el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir tu objetivo necesitas las plantillas variádicas. Esto son un tipo especial de plantillas que admiten un número indeterminado de argumentos.

Un ejemplo:

```
template<int ... Args>
int suma_mult(int T)
{
    int data[] = { Args ... };
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 0, [T](int accum, int value){ return accum + (value * T); });
}

std::cout << suma_mult<1, 2, 3, 4>(5);
```

Comment: Sugiero la alternativa `std::accumulate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 0) * T`.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Dónde sumo la multiplicación de un número por `T`? asi:

Dado que estás escribiendo una función plantilla (en inglés *template*), tendrás que hacerlo en el cuerpo de la función:

```
template<int... num; typename T>
T suma_mult(T x){ }
//      Aquí --> ^
```

Puedes hacerlo con una *fold expression*:

```
template<int... num, typename T>
T suma_mult(T x){ return ((num * x) + ...); }
//   fold expression --> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Una [*fold expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold?msclkid=8ab5874cc56811ecae33516fe26847d0) es una expresión que contiene el símbolo de elipsis (los [puntos suspensivos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntos_suspensivos?msclkid=b9dcddc9c56811eca7d7870551cb4061)) junto a otras operaciones; el compilador se encargará de repetir la expresión tantas veces como elementos tenga el paquete de parámetros contenido en la elipsis. Por ejemplo, este código:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << suma_mult<1, 2, 3>(3.1415);
    return 0;
}
```

Instancia la plantilla `suma_mult` de la siguiente manera:

```
double suma_mult(double x){ return ((1 * x) + (2 * x) + (3 * x)); }
```

[Generando la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##RcxLCoMwFIXhsXcVFzqJ9UHVdqKpq3BeQkxFSGLQG2gRt940g0Knh/N/0rlCamGnEE6zldqPCvm8bLQqYXoAUsZpQYrPlsqyROtNjvR2ygqjcOhhwM0b8TBeExvwle64KvKrRcbiF89xwgxjmnZ4AEQGjZgtS2GHZKOxbeXiCTn/O7zKsc6x6VlTVtfqlnaQ/NBLB0cIH/nUYtpCEfu7zLJafAE):

> ```
> 18.849
> ```